# IBM PCOMM - Unable to call a vbs macro from within another vbs macro

Tags: vbscript, mainframe, ibm-pcomm

I've made a credentials input macro using the macro recorder of IBM Personal Communications 12.0.3.0. It simply enters my username and password when called.

```
sub Creds()

   Dim username
   Dim password

   username = "myUser"
   password = "myPass"


   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys username

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys password

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

end sub
```

During other workflows I often have to enter my username/password multiple times to switch between windows, so I thought it would be simpler for these newer macros to just call `Creds()` when that type of prompt shows up. I have to change my mainframe password often as well so only replacing the password text once in the `Creds()` macro would be ideal.

Here is an example where I would like to use the stored `Creds()` procedure:

```
sub Login()

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "server name"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLPS.StartMacro "Creds"
   
end sub
```

My problem exists in the line `autECLSession.autECLPS.StartMacro "Creds"`. With other attempts where I tried to use more classic vbscript commands to run the macro I would get an execution error, but with the `... .StartMacro "Creds"` line - **nothing happens**.

---

Based on [this documentation by IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/personal-communications/13.0?topic=s-parameters-16), the `StartMacro(String MacroName)` method should run the macro file located in the PCOMM user-class application data directory indicated by the `MacroName` parameter. I have both macros stored as separate `.mac` files in the user-class app data directory (`"%APPDATA%\IBM\PersonalCommunications\"`) as specified [here under 'typical installation'](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_12.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/pdf/install_guideV60.pdf).

This is what I meant by a typical vbs attempt to call another macro (in place of `StartMacro()`):

```
'doesn't work
Shell "C:\Users\marcucciboy2\AppData\Roaming\IBM\Personal Communications\Creds.mac" 

'neither works
dim ObjShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ObjShell.Run "cscript C:\Users\marcucciboy2\AppData\Roaming\IBM\Personal Communications\Creds.mac"
'ObjShell.Run "cscript \\C:\Users\marcucciboy2\AppData\Roaming\IBM\Personal Communications\Creds.mac"
```

Here are two related question that I found in my research [one](http://ibmmainframes.com/about65232.html), [two](http://ibmmainframes.com/about66605.html), but unfortunately neither of them has a working answer.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Is using PowerShell an option?

Comment: To be clear, i'm open to anything :)

Comment: Note that these two subroutines exist in separate files. I'd bet that putting them into a single file would allow one to call the other, BUT, I don't know how I could call each one separately in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The first link from your research states that *If (macro file) has an extension, you need to either remove the extension so the call can find the macro file, or add the extension to the call statement filename*. You mention that both are `.mac` files so you could give this a try:

```
autECLSession.autECLPS.StartMacro "Credentials.mac"
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking a stab at this problem, but no luck with that answer. I get the error `Error in the script on line 21. ECL37100: Emulator interface (EHLLAPI) error. Reason code 9. Would you like to edit the script?`

Answer (score 0):

It also says that long file names are not supported. e.g., over 8 characters. Try a shorter name for that macro file.

> **Parameters:**
> String MacroName
> Name of macro file located in the Personal
> Communications user-class application data
> directory (specified at installation), ***without the file
> extension***. This method does not support long file
> names.

> **Usage Notes:**
> You must use the short file name for the macro name. This method does not
> support long file names.

Comment: Thanks for replying Gave, I appreciate it! I changed the file and function names to "Creds" rather than "Credentials" but I'm still not having any luck :/

Comment: If you want this to work, strip out the wait statements and have it only fill in the input fields. Working with it some more, the code 9 error will show up as soon as you have any wait conditions or the presentation  space is updated, as in changing screens. So you can call a another macro that does simple things but as soon as the emulator enters a wait state you get code 9 error. There is probably a way around this but examples on a 20+ year old use case are hard to find.